# добавить функциональность FindBugs в pom.xml

Tags: maven, tomcat

Всем привет.

Помогите добавить функциональность *FindBugs* в `pom.xml`.
Как это сделать новым `profile`?

Мой `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
        <version>myVersion</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>myName</name>
        <description>myDescription</description>

        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> 
        </parent>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>


</project>
```

Спасибо.